# Exchange 2010 PowerShell: Cannot bind argument

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to remove orphaned user objects from all mailboxes in our Exchange server.

When I execute this command:

```
get-mailboxpermission * | where {$_.User -like "S-1-5-21*"} | foreach {$_.Identity.Name}
```

It correctly returns a list with all the mailboxes that still have orphaned user account permissions set on them.

However, when I try to remove them by doing this:

```
get-mailboxpermission * | where {$_.User -like "S-1-5-21*"} | remove-mailboxpermission -identity $_.Identity.Name -user $_.User -accessrights $_.AccessRights -deny:$_.Deny
```

It returns this error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-MailboxPermission], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Remove-MailboxPermission
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_` doesn't work like that, you need to wrap the `Remove-MailboxPermission` statement in `ForEach-Object {}`:

```
Get-MailboxPermission * | Where-Object {$_.User -like "S-1-5-21*"} | ForEach-Object {
  Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity.Name -User $_.User -AccessRights $_.AccessRights -Deny:$_.Deny
}
```

Since Exchange doesn't seem to like nested pipelines very much, you could simply to away with the parameter arguments altogether (`Remove-MailboxPermission` will automatically bind the permissions from the pipeline):

```
Get-MailboxPermission * | Where-Object {$_.User -like "S-1-5-21*"} | Remove-MailboxPermission
```

Comment: I've already tried this and got the error `Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently`. `Get-MailboxPermission` and `Remove-MailboxPermission` are designed to take pipeline input from each other so there's no need to use `ForEach`. [see this link](http://mikepfeiffer.net/2010/02/exchange-management-shell-error-pipelines-cannot-be-executed-concurrently/)

Comment: @mariu5 My bad. Is there a reason you specify all those parameters with `Remove-MailboxPermission`? `Get-MailboxPermission|Remove-MailboxPermission` should suffice

Comment: That did the trick! I thought you would have to specify the exact permission in order to remove it but apparently, that isn't necessary. Thanks for your help. If you edit your answer, I could mark it as a solution if you like.